# What's the best way to check if a proxy workable in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm sending HTTP requests with QNetworkAccessManager [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/network/http/httpwindow.cpp?h=5.15).

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName("some proxy IP");
proxy.setPort(5555);
network_manager.setProxy(proxy);
```

I want to check if a proxy can work before using it. I know I can just send a HTTP request to google with this proxy. But it will receive more than 1K data. It's relatively large since I would test many proxies. I don't think that's a good way. And I wanted to send ping via the proxy server. Seems [no good way to send ping with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082192/make-a-ping-function-with-qtcpsocket). If I use the WinAPI IcmpSendEcho to send ping, there's no way to assign a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the proxy using HTTP you could try and connect to the proxy using a `QTcpSocket` and see if the connection is actually established. If so you can proceed using the proxy address and port for further connections.

Comment: I picked a workable proxy for a QTcpSocket. Received error message `QAbstractSocket::UnsupportedSocketOperationError`

Comment: Checked the ports? Otherwise this is what the official documentation states regarding that error type: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum.